# Dynamic callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is it possible to dynamically add a callback to every function encapsulated within a function/coffeescript class? Like an `after_filter` in `rails`.

For example:

```
class Parent
  after_every_function_call_myCallback
  myCallback: ->
    console.log “callback called“

class Child extends Parent
  doSomething: ->
    console.log “a function“

class Regular 
  doSomething: ->
    console.log “a regular function“

> reg = new Regular()
> reg.doSomething()
< “a regular function“
> child = new Child()
> child.doSomething()
< “a function“
< “callback called“
```

Comment: Nop. You could create a decorator that you apply to every function manually, or you can loop prototype properties and extend the functions. But as a feature this doesn't exist.

Comment: How would I loop prototype properties? Can I keep them encapsulated?

Comment: `for k, f of Child::` to loop, then you can `Child::[k] = after Parent::myCallback, f`, where `after` is a higher-order function that decorates another function. But again, it is manual, at least if you want to use Coffee classes

Comment: Interesting, do you think it could be done better another way, like without Coffee classes?

Comment: @elclanrs, if you put your comments into an answer I'll accept it because its a great solution and the right solution to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a feature this doesn't exist, but you could create a decorator that you apply to every function in the prototype manually:

```
after = (g, f) ->
  ->
    f()
    g()

class Parent
  myCallback: ->
    console.log 'callback called'

class Child extends Parent
  doSomething: ->
    console.log 'a function'

for k, f of Child::
  Child::[k] = after Parent::myCallback, f

child = new Child
child.doSomething()
# a function
# callback called
```

With a bit of abstraction you could reuse it for other classes, still a bit manual though:

```
decorate = (decor, f, clazz) ->
  for k, g of clazz::
    clazz::[k] = decor f, g
  clazz

class Child extends Parent
  doSomething: ->
    console.log 'a function'

decorate after, Parent::myCallback, Child
```